# Is there a way to output stdout (and/or stderror) to the plasma desktop?

Tags: bash, kde

I have created a desktop file that invokes a bash script to mount or unmount my network shares (webdav and samba).

Sometimes, the umount operation fails because the `umount` command returns ("device is busy"). As I invoke the command through a script, is there a way to output stdout (and/or stderror) of a bash script to the plasma desktop?

I am running Kubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Maybe try with `notify-send`? You may need to install `libnotify-bin`.

Comment: Sounds interesting (and is already installed, though I did not manage to get it to work yet.

Comment: I'm guessing you'd have to include some sort of test for your umount command and trigger a notify-send conditionally?

Comment: notify-send "$(mount| grep mountpoint)"  seems to work to check if mounted.

Comment: you could run the command in a terminal (`Konsole`, `Yakuake`)

Comment: @jfs i thought my question is clear with regard to my intentions...I know that I can read standard output and standard error in a terminal. I would like to output it to the graphical desktop.

Comment: @Bruni both programs that I've mentioned are for "graphical desktop".

Comment: @Jfs now you are playing with semantics. Not very helpful.

Comment: @Bruni I'm sure there  are people who interpret your question the same way I did and for them my comment may be helpful. Questions  on SE are not only for a single person who happens to ask it first.